# Extract rows from a matrix based of values from another matrix

Tags: r, select, matrix, rows

I need your help!

I am trying to pull out rows of the second matrix based on IDs from the first matrix. To check that my function (which is not provided here) works correctly, I run the following code (CritMat is the second matrix and parms is the first):

```r
results <- matrix(0, nrow = 15, ncol = 8)
colnames(results) <- c("alpha", "beta", "omega", "T=64", "T=128", "T=256", "T=512", "T=1024")
for (r in 1:15) {
    results [r,] <- CritMat[CritMat[, 1] == parms[r, 2] & CritMat[, 2] == 
    parms[r, 1] & CritMat[, 3] == parms[r, 3] , ]
    print(results[r,])
}
```

The loop works for the first 4 iterations followed by the following error message for the fifth:

```
*Error in results[r, ] <- CritMat[CritMat[, 1] == parms[r, 2] & CritMat[,  : 
  replacement has length zero*
```

Any idea why this happens and solution.
Many thanks
AA

****parms matrix****

```
 beta  alpha omega
```

1  0.005 0.005 0.990

2  0.240 0.005 0.755

3  0.490 0.005 0.505

4  0.740 0.005 0.255

5  0.990 0.005 0.005

6  0.005 0.250 0.745

7  0.240 0.250 0.510

8  0.490 0.250 0.260

9  0.740 0.250 0.010

10 0.005 0.500 0.495

11 0.240 0.500 0.260

12 0.490 0.500 0.010

13 0.005 0.750 0.245

14 0.240 0.750 0.010

15 0.005 0.990 0.005

****CritMat matrix****

```
 alpha  beta omega      T.64     T.128     T.256     T.512    T.1024
```

1  0.005 0.005 0.990 -2.956420 -2.919654 -2.921704 -2.886429 -2.879443

2  0.005 0.240 0.755 -2.959242 -2.917744 -2.923356 -2.885018 -2.881905

3  0.005 0.490 0.505 -2.959395 -2.915798 -2.927405 -2.886637 -2.885186

4  0.005 0.740 0.255 -2.957763 -2.912088 -2.934518 -2.890182 -2.889484

5  0.005 0.990 0.005 -2.937999 -2.857668 -2.864637 -2.819950 -2.820588

6  0.250 0.005 0.745 -2.987160 -2.986864 -2.897846 -2.865875 -2.911572

7  0.250 0.240 0.510 -3.034868 -2.979375 -2.924888 -2.875446 -2.898752

8  0.250 0.490 0.260 -3.052279 -2.995942 -2.969414 -2.926178 -2.918958

9  0.250 0.740 0.010 -3.197169 -3.263336 -3.258011 -3.202253 -3.248068

10 0.500 0.005 0.495 -3.031267 -3.038585 -2.936348 -2.921126 -2.908868

11 0.500 0.240 0.260 -3.142031 -3.086536 -3.026555 -3.079825 -2.871080

12 0.500 0.490 0.010 -3.383052 -3.410789 -3.431221 -3.367462 -3.332024

13 0.750 0.005 0.245 -3.209441 -3.170385 -3.112472 -3.141569 -2.925559

14 0.750 0.240 0.010 -3.452131 -3.517234 -3.428402 -3.477691 -3.178128

15 0.990 0.005 0.005 -3.427804 -3.491805 -3.298037 -3.290127 -3.087541

Comment: I can't see how this works for the first 4 iterations. The `results` matrix has 8 columns, but each row of `CrimMat` has 9 columns. You should get a different type of error at the first iteration. The process should not be able to replace 8 values with 9 values. However, if you're willing to try a more efficient way check how to join your 2 datasets on columns `alpha`, `beta` and `omega`. Join is doing exactly what you're trying to do with a for-loop.

Comment: Sorry I copied the column called T.64 twice. Ignore the one with teh 6 decimal places. Thanks for the advice though. I am doing this in a function  which uses one row at a time, so pulling out one row at a time is the best way. I too am puzzled at why it works for only 4 iterations..

Comment: I've removed the extra column from the CritMat matrix.

Comment: I think the problem occurs when you don't find a match on the table `CritMat` and then your process tries to replace a row of 8 zeros with nothing. Based on the data you provided I get that error on the second iteration. There's no `alpha` with a value of 0.240 on table `CritMat`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think that the lines in the matrices changed during copy and paste in here. I will try to copy it again and hoe that the ordering is maintained. Thanks again!

Comment: If you really need to use a for-loop in every iteration you should check if you get a row from `CritMat`, or not. If you don't get a row you should create something to return (maybe NAs), or leave the zeros as they are. If you are trying to find an efficient and faster way (if you ever get more data) try the `merge` function to join/merge datasets.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I had already merged the two so CritMat has alpha, beta and omega already and I used it directly and that works. I just could not see what was right in front of me.. Still curious about why I was getting the results though. Many thanks for your time.